# AVPlayers in UICollectionViewCells eventually crash app after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, grand-central-dispatch, avplayer

I am trying to create an app similar to Vine where it is just a feed of cells and the videos autoplay when you scroll and stop on a cell.

Each `UICollectionViewCell` has it's own `AVPlayer`.

Right now my current setup works alright for the most part, but after scrolling for awhile the app eventually crashes and my analytics SDK shows that the crash is caused by the following error:

```
An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer
```

The app also crashes sometimes right after I receive a memory warning in the console.

I have a feeling that it has to do with how I am setting up the `AVPlayers` for each `UICollectionViewCell`, and how the cells are being reused, but I'm not entirely sure.

Here is the code that I have so far in my View Controller that deals with setting up the cells and their `AVPlayers`:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   MyCollectionViewCellSubclass *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   [cell load:self.objectsFromServer[indexPath.row] withBannerColor:self.bannerColors[indexPath.row % self.bannerColors.count]];

   QBCOCustomObject *objectFromServer = self.objectsFromServer[indexPath.row];

   NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:objectFromServer.fields[@"Video_URL"]];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        cell.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:videoURL];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            cell.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:cell.playerItem];
            cell.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:cell.player];
            cell.playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

            cell.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
            cell.playerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 186.5);
            [cell.banner.layer addSublayer:cell.playerLayer];

        });
    });

}
  return cell;
}
```

I use `scrollViewDidScroll:` to handle playing/pausing of cells. I check to make sure the currently visible cell isn't the lastPlayingCell / the one playing video and if it's not then I pause the lastPlayingCell and play the now visible cell's video.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{ 

// Play/Pause Video
CGRect visibleRect = (CGRect){.origin = self.collectionView.contentOffset, .size = self.collectionView.bounds.size};
CGPoint visiblePoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect));
NSIndexPath *visibleIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:visiblePoint];
NSLog(@"%@",visibleIndexPath);

MyCollectionViewCellSubclass *cell = (MyCollectionViewCellSubclass *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:visibleIndexPath];

if (cell != self.lastPlayingCell) {

    [self.lastPlayingCell pauseVideo];
    self.lastPlayingCell = cell;
    [cell playVideo];
  }
}
```

Comment: I got something similaire but instead of autoplay video in my app are played by click so could you share with me how AVPlayer is implemented inside the CollectionViewCell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line, `[cell.banner.layer addSublayer:cell.playerLayer]`; will add a new playerLayer whenever a cell is reused. You need to check if the cell already has a player before adding one. If it already has one, use `replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:` to give the player a new `AVPlayerItem`.

Comment: So should I check if the cell has a player, if it DOES then I should NOT add cell.playerLayer and should also use replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:?

Comment: @user3344977, yes I think so.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly and solved the issue. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: @rdelmar: I tried your solution but the reuse cell can not play video. This is my source code: BOOL isFound = NO;
            for (AVPlayerLayer *layer in cell.playerView.layer.sublayers) {
                if ([layer isKindOfClass:[AVPlayerLayer class]]) {
                    isFound = YES;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if (!isFound) {
                [cell.playerView.layer addSublayer:cell.playerLayer];
            }
            else{
                [cell.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:cell.playerItem];
            }